# Flex: post without showing

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, post, urlrequest

```
var url:String = "http://www.[yourDomain].com/application.jsp";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.exampleSessionId = new Date().getTime();
variables.exampleUserLabel = "guest";
request.data = variables;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

navigateToURL(request);
```

This example is the functionality I want to achieve, however i want to make this happen in the background. This code opens a window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `URLLoader` and call its `load()` method to do stuff "in the background".

```
var url:String = "http://www.[yourDomain].com/application.jsp";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.exampleSessionId = new Date().getTime();
variables.exampleUserLabel = "guest";

request.data = variables;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
ldr.load(req);
```

If you're sending data back then you can manage this through an `Event`.

```
ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _dataBack);

function _dataBack(e:Event):void
{
    var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(e.target.data);
    //do stuff with vars

    removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _dataBack);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`sendToURL()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#sendToURL%28%29) ignores any response